# Flask-Python : Generating TextFields in a for loop and rendering in jinja using wtfForms

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

So here is my form Class:

```
exchangeNames=["one","two","three"]
class addExchange_All(Form):

apis={}
secrets={}

for exchangeName in exchangesNames:

    apis[exchangeName+"_api"] = TextField(
                    description=('Enter %s Api Key:', exchangeName))

    secrets[exchangeName+'_secret'] = TextField(validators=[RequiredIf(exchangeName+'_api')],
                description=('Enter %s Api Key:', exchangeName))


submit = SubmitField('Update Exchange Credentials')
```

And here is my route function:

```
@account.route('/manage/exchanges', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def exchanges():
    form=addExchange_All()
    return render_template('/account/exchanges.html', form=form)
```

I am trying to render all the fields in exchanges.html like so :

```
            <div class="two fields">   

           {%for a in form.apis%}
           {{f.render_form_field(a)}}
           {%endfor%}
           {%for a in form.secrets%}
           {{f.render_form_field(a)}}
           {%endfor%}

        </div>
```

and here is the render_form_field macro :

```
{# Render a field for the form #}
{% macro render_form_field(field, extra_classes='') %}
{% if field.type == 'Radio Field' %}
    {% set extra_classes = extra_classes + ' grouped fields' %}
{% endif %}
<div class="field {% if field.errors %}error{% endif %} {{ 
extra_classes }}">
    {{ render_form_input(field) }}
    {% if field.errors %}
        <div class="ui red pointing label">
            {{ field.errors[0] | safe }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

The template renders without errors but no textfields are rendered. I have tried several different solutions, like saving them to locals() but nothing seems to work. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the answer, I don't have time to check it so I'm happy if someone will correct me and I'll learn something.

Anyway the way I have built dynamic forms is to not use dicts and have each item as a separate element as a class attribute in the following way:

```
def create_dynamic_form():
    class addExchange_All(Form):
        submit = SubmitField('Update Exchange Credentials')
        pass

    for exchangeName in ["One","Two","Three"]:
        setattr(addExchange_All, exchangeName+"_api", TextField(
            description=('Enter '+exchangeName+' Api Key:')))
        setattr(addExchange_All, exchangeName+'_secret', TextField(
            validators=[RequiredIf(exchangeName+'_api')],
            description=('Enter '+exchangeName+' Api Key:')))

    return addExchange_All()
```

Then use:

```
form=create_dynamic_form() # instead of addExchange_All()
```

Comment: Gives me the following error: 

File "/home/puru991/flask-saas/flask-base/app/account/forms.py", line 216
14:31:14 worker.1 |     setattr(addExchange_All, exchangeName+'_secret', (TextField(

I think its because of the four arguments. setattr() only accepts 3.

Comment: setattr( object, name, value) has 3 args: in this case it adds the value TextField(..) to addExchange_All class with the attribute name: 'xxe_api'.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was stuck here for a while!

Comment: please accept answer if it ended in solution, thanks.